# Ports allowed for an application

Tags: tcp, port

Can an application use two different ports simultaneously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes , if and only if it is not already occupied

Answer (score 1):

In general, yes.  Just open two sockets.

Of course there may be a firewall present and the firewall may not be configured to allow the application to use both ports.  But most any firewall should support the ability to configure a range (or multiple distinct ranges) of ports as accessible to a given application.

Comment: -1: A firewall shouldn't stop you using two ports. It should only stop someone from the outside from connecting _to_ those ports.

Comment: @Jon Cage - Um, no.  Some firewalls work both ways, and will block both incoming and outgoing connections.  If the firewall blocks outgoing connections, and has not been configured to allow the application access to both of the desired outgoing ports, then it will interfere with the application.  Of course, if we are talking about listening on a port, a firewall will not stop you from binding on as many ports as you want.  But nothing in the question suggests that incoming connections are the only use-case being considered.

Comment: If you can provide an example I'll change the downvote to an upvote, but personally, I think it's irrelevent information. There's all sorts of things that might stop you making a connection, but the OP only asked whether it's possible to use multiple ports.

Comment: This is not an uncommon feature.  It is used frequently in corporate networks.  So frequently, in fact, that Flash has a built-in feature where it will fall back to RTMPT on port 80 if it cannot access the standard RTMP port (1935).  It is also supported by the [Win7 Firewall](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-security/need-help-windows-7-firewall-rules/a37ac15b-c599-4366-8adf-39427251dc7e).  The OP asked if they could use two ports.  To me that means "use successfully", and a firewall can prevent that and be very difficult to debug if you're not aware of the fact.

Comment: Fair enough - at least now you have some evidence to back up what you put forward. I still think this is more configuration mind you. The OP should probably also know they need a NIC, another machine and an ethernet cable (if it's a wired connection) etc. etc... ...you see my point?